# GPU usage via scripts or API

Tags: windows, gpu

is there any way to find the GPU usage in windows?

Either via scripts (vb, tcl,...)

or any API or library in high level languages.

Comment: I also found this answer relevant: [how to get gpu usage and gpu memory info of a process by poweshell](https://superuser.com/questions/1632758/how-to-get-gpu-usage-and-gpu-memory-info-of-a-process-by-powershell7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Riva Tuner](http://www.guru3d.com/index.php?page=rivatuner) has an SDK to allow plugins / other applications to access GPU statistics, such as current clock speed, current fan speed, current temperature, GPU load, etc.